# How to create a root level folder in Chrome bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm getting mad with the bookmark manager in Google Chrome. I understand that I can create folders, but for some reason it only works for me that it creates a subfolder of the current selected root folder.

I have 2 folder standard:

- Bookmark bar
- Other bookmarks

One of them is always selected, I cannot unselect them when creating a new folder. How can I create another folder on that level, not a sub folder.

So I want:

- Bookmark bar
- Other bookmarks
- My new folder

and NOT

- Bookmark bar

  - My new folder
- Other bookmarks

Hope you get my point.

Comment: You can't, this is by design. Bookmarks under *Bookmark bar* are visible on the bookmark bar, bookmarks under *Other bookmarks* are not. There's no third option.

Comment: @gronostaj so I only can create folders under Other bookmarks or Bookmark bar? There is actually a third folder popping up named `mobile bookmarks` when using Chrome on mobile. But thats just as a side note.

Comment: Yes, top folders seem to be predefined.

Comment: @gronostaj I see, thats a shame but okay..

Comment: You could probably create a script or extension that changes where folders are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three top folder are not real folders, they are telling you how their content is treated (displayed/not displayed/only displayed on mobile devices).
That is a fixed list and cannot be extended.

Any folders you add would be either visible in the bookmark bar, or not visible, right? (Or visible only on mobile). So they will be shown inside the respective lists.

Comment: disagree with the second paragraph as Google Chrome shows the folder "Other bookmarks" on the right handed site of the Bookmark bar. So I thought creating another folder on the level I'm talking about will show another folder on the Bookmark bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you alter your definition of "top level", you *can* get a new folder in the top level of the Bookmarks folder.

[image]

It is worth mentioning this because if you don't use the Bookmarks toolbar, adding a folder to the Bookmarks Bar adds the folder to the top level of the Bookmarks menu, which is as top-level as it gets.

Details:

Bookmarks > Bookmark Manager > Select Bookmarks Bar > Click the "..." menu for Bookmarks (not the "..." menu for an individual folder) > "Add new folder"

Comment: OK, but how do you do it?

Comment: The OP specifically says this isn't what he wants in his question.